# How to set new env vars in thingsboard(angular) web-ui and add them to docker config for kubernetes

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, thingsboard

I have a project build on thingsboard, I added the new env vars in tb-web-ui.conf. Should I add them to custom-environment-variables.yml ? because it seems they are only there for logging purposes. using .env file and running the project locally works. But I want to prepare them for kubernetes and pass them to the tb-web-ui container. How to do that